# Why is my firebase store the name in email and email in name?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having an issue with firebase when i create a new account everytime it puts the email in the name field and the email in the name field. Is there any way to fix this?

I have attached the image of what i mean and will gladly paste any part of my code if needed at all!

My create account fragment:

```
package com.example.soulforge.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.soulforge.ReplacerActivity;
import com.example.soulforge.MainActivity;
import com.example.soulforge.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class CreateAccountFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText nameEt, emailEt, passwordEt, confirmPasswordEt;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView loginTv;
    private Button signUpBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    public static final String EMAIL_REGEX = "(.+)@(.+)$";





    public CreateAccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_account, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        init(view);

        clickListener();

    }

    private void init(View view){
        nameEt = view.findViewById(R.id.nameET);
        emailEt = view.findViewById(R.id.emailET);
        passwordEt = view.findViewById(R.id.passwordET);
        confirmPasswordEt = view.findViewById(R.id.confirmPassET);
        loginTv = view.findViewById(R.id.loginTV);
        signUpBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);

        auth =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    private void clickListener() {
        loginTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ((ReplacerActivity) getActivity()).setFragment(new LoginFragment());

            }
        });

        signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = nameEt.getText().toString();
                String email = emailEt.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordEt.getText().toString();
                String confirmPassword = confirmPasswordEt.getText().toString();

                if (name.isEmpty() || name.equals(" ")){
                    nameEt.setError("Please input a valid name");
                    return;
                }

                if (email.isEmpty() || !email.matches(EMAIL_REGEX)){
                    emailEt.setError("Please input valid email");
                    return;
                }

                if (password.isEmpty() || password.length()< 6){
                    passwordEt.setError("Please input a valid password longer than 6 characters");
                    return;
                }
                if (confirmPassword.isEmpty() || !password.equals(confirmPassword)){
                    passwordEt.setError("Passwords do not match");
                    return;
                }
//                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                createAccount(email,name, password);
            }
        });

    }
    private void createAccount(String name, String email, String password){

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            uploadUser(user, email, name);

                        } else {
//                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            String exception = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: "+exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
    // ISSUE LIES HERE
    private void uploadUser(FirebaseUser user, String email, String name){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", name);
        map.put("email", email);
        map.put("profileImage", "");
        map.put("uid", user.getUid());

        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(user.getUid())
                .set(map)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            assert getActivity() !=null;
//                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                        }else{
//                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: "+task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some code if you need some help!

Comment: Im just confused which part of my code to add :D

Comment: The part that related to firestore, which you use method `add` or `update`.

Comment: I've added my createaccount fragment

Answer (score 0):

After adding some code, all the problem is you are mis-arranging your parameters

You need to change this

`createAccount(email,name, password);`

To this

`createAccount(name, email, password);`

Hope you find your way.

Comment: same issue still happens sadly

Comment: Which is it now?

Comment: in the firebase it still store the wrong way round

Comment: Try uninstall your application from phone, and try again.

Comment: Still the same sadly

Comment: As mentioned, the parameters in your `createAccount` method need to be changed. Additionally, it would worthwhile looking at how you have mapped your `EditText`. `nameEt = view.findViewById(R.id.nameET)` -> Is this really the name or email field?
`emailEt = view.findViewById(R.id.emailET)` -> Is this really the email or name field?